# Visual Studio Code only show the content inside the directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, files-folders

The Visual Studio Code only shows the content inside the directory and not the directory name. Besides, I can't have multiple directories at the same time.

[image]

How do I change the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your **Open Editors** and directory **Outline** have been hidden. Right click on the Explorer section and see if they are disabled.

[image: Hidden]

Enable them and your setup should return to normal.

[image: Enabled]

[VS Code has multi-root workspaces since 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251993). You can go to **File** > **Add Folder to Workspace...** to add multiple directories.

[image: Add Folder to Workspace]

You will now have an untitled workspace and you can save the workspace to keep it.

[image: Workspace]

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue.

Comment: @Arefe Awesome, glad to hear the issue is resolved! If I have answered your question completely, you can choose to accept it as the answer. If not, you can always wait for a better answer.